# Does the expression converge?

Tags: calculus

if $f(x):=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\cdots}}}$ with $0\leq x\leq 1$ I know that, if
$a_1(x)=\sqrt{x},\, a_2(x)=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}},\, a_3(x)=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}},\ldots.$
then $a_n(x)$ is bounded a increasing, next, the limit is $L=\sqrt{x+L}$ therefore $L=\frac{1}{2}({1+\sqrt{4x+1}})$.

Question 1. Why is it not possible to make $L=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+L}}$ for conclude that $L\in \left\{\frac{1}{2}(1\pm \sqrt{4x+1}), y=\frac{1}{2}(-1\pm\sqrt{4x-3})\right\}$

Comment: For all $x>0$, $f(x)$ remains positive. However, $L=\frac{1}{2}(-1\pm\sqrt{4x-3})$ is negative/complex for certain values, thus discard it and consider it extraneous. It is possible set $L=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+L}}$, but only consider certain solutions (that make sense).

Comment: It is possible, and still correct. (Assuming the limit exists,) The correct value of $L$ is still within that set.

Comment: @sreysus That argument (of discarding an expression for all cases just because it's negative/complex in some cases) need not be correct in the general case. The limit could be one expression in some cases, and another expression in other cases.  Maybe if you added in an argument of why the limit must be continuous, we could then exclude an expression (if they do not intersect).

Comment: @CalvinLin In this particular problem, continuity is not needed.  You know that for any fixed value of $~x \in (0,1),~$ that $~L~$ must be some element in $~\displaystyle \left\{ \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4x}  ~\right]  ~\right\}.~$  However, the *smaller* element of this set is always negative, and $~L~$ can never be negative.

Comment: You can write it simpler with $L=\sqrt{x+L}$.

Comment: @VukJovovic True, but my way makes it easy to see that the smaller value must always be rejected.

Comment: @user2661923 The solution should be chosen cautiosly, yes.

Comment: @CalvinLin Actually, I mis-spoke.  Continuity is needed, in that you have to show that for a fixed value $~X_0,~$ the function $~g(n) = a_n(X_0)~$ is a continuous function in the variable $~n.~$  This is what allows you to conclude that $~L = \sqrt{X_0 + L}.~$ My oversight.

Comment: @user2661923 You're missing my point. OP is asking if we can check any equation that $L$ satisfies to guess at / restrict the value of $L$, and the answer is "Yes". Of course, it could make it harder to select the true value of $L$. EG $L=L$ so we can conclude that $ L \in \mathbb{R}$ (or $ \mathbb{C}$), even though that conclusion is trivial. $\quad$ Also, note that we don't _need_ continuity. There are other ways of showing that it converges to $L_+ = (1/2) (1 + \sqrt{4x+1} )$ pointwise. EG By studying $ |a_ i - L_+ |$

Comment: In summary: for each $x\ in [0,1]$ the sequence $a_n(x)$ es monotone and bounded, therefore, converges to $L_x$. Now, $L_x=\sqrt{x+L_x}$ implies that $L_x=(1/2)(1\pm \sqrt{4x+1})$, but, $0\leq x$ implies that $L(x)\geq 0$. Therefore, $L(x)=(1/2)(1+\sqrt{4x+1})$ it's the correct value. It's right?

Answer (score 0):

*Not an answer.* Just wanted to write a full proof why $f_n(x)$ converge,

Define $f_1(x)=\sqrt x$, $f_{n+1}(x)=\sqrt{x+ f_n(x)}$

Since $\sqrt x > \sqrt y $ if $x>y\ge 0 $ then it is clear that $ f_2(x)> f_1(x)$.

Assume that $f_{k+1}(x)>f_k(x)$, then $f_{k+2}(x) = \sqrt{x+ f_{k+1}(x) }>\sqrt{x+ f_{k}(x) }= f_{k+1}(x)$. By induction the sequence $f_n(x)$ is monotone increasing for every $x$.

For $0\le x\le 1$, $f_n(x) \le f_n(1) , \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}  $.

$f_1(1) =1 <2$ , assume  $f_k(1)< 2$ then $f_{k+1}(1)= \sqrt{1+f_k(1)}<\sqrt{1+2}=\sqrt3 < 2$. By induction $f_n(1) $ is bounded above by $2$  which mean the sequence is bounded above by $2$.

By monotone convergence theorem $f_n(x) $ converge for all $x$.

> $\textbf{Monotone convergence theorem:-}$A monotone sequence of Real numbers converge if it  bounded.

Comment: @Gonçalo Why ? I used induction to show that $f_n(1)<2$ for all $n$